# If you put string data(name : test) with html tags in `<div v-html="test"/>`, the tags do not work

Tags: html, vuejs2

I'm using Vue2.

However, if you put string data(name : test) with html tags in `<div v-html="test"/>`, the tags do not work.

Tags like h2 are visible.
However, em tags, ol tags, li tags, hr tags, ul tags, and blockquote tags are not applied and are displayed on the screen.

How can HTML tags be properly applied and displayed on the screen?
The example is very simple. What I want is also very simple.
I hope you can help me. thank you.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-html="test"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      test: '<em>tttttest</em>',
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

I'll show you the picture I ran.
[image]

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app', // Vue 인스턴스를 연결할 DOM 요소 선택자
    data() {
        return {
            test: '<em>tttttest</em>', // 데이터 속성
        };
    },
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Vue.js Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div v-html="test"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It works fine in snippet. I know. But in my local's vue project the task is not working. What is the reason and how can I fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The screenshot shows the value from the `test` prop in your div. So at least this works. I guess you are asking why the text is not cursive? Have you checked the browser developer tools if some CSS is affecting it? Also, you can use the `<>` button to create a runnable snippet, it can even add Vue.

Comment: Added snippet. And if you operate it locally, the tilt is not applied. What is the reason and how to solve it?

Comment: Well open your browser's developer tools. It shows which CSS rules are applied and might help you find why. em doesn't have to be cursive if some CSS rule changes or overrides it. The snippet you added shows the text in cursive so there is surely some CSS in your project that influences this.

Comment: You were right. The common scss of node modules was being used through webpack. But I don't want to apply this scss in only one component. Is there a way?

Comment: How about using a [soped style tag](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#mixing-local-and-global-styles) for this component? It can style only this *em* in this component.

Comment: I know I can override styles using scoped. But other than this method, is there a way to prevent scss, which is applied globally, from being applied only to specific components?

Additionally, I would like to thank you for kindly answering my questions.

Comment: Sure, you're welcome. There is no perfectly reliable way. You want a style only applied in this component but you don't want the style only applied in this component..? It's a weird requirement. You can always add a class to your em tag (or any tag) and make a CSS selector for it and style it that way, wouldn't need to be scoped.

Comment: Oh, I said that confusingly. 
To be exact, reset.scss received from the node module is interfering with the basic effect of the em tag. So, I want reset.scss to be applied to other components, but I don't want reset.scss to be applied to the div to which the em tag belongs. 
You can overwrite the style, but is there a way to prevent rest.scss from being applied without overwriting it? 

This is because only the em tag was mentioned for simple explanation, but in fact, other tags such as ol and ul are also in the same situation.

Comment: No this is intentional behavior of CSS. You are supposed to override styles for specific cases. This is the "cascading" part in CSS's name - to define multiple rules for the same element, which then are collapsed into one valid styling for any element. See also [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: I achieved what I wanted by overriding style. thank you

Comment: Should I post a summary of my comments as an answer?

Comment: yes! Of course!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Scoped component style

Documentation: [Vue Loader: Scoped CSS](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#mixing-local-and-global-styles)

The Vue loader offers a component's style tag to be scoped. This means that the styling will only apply to this component.

Syntax:

```html
<style scoped>
em {
  font-style: italic;
}
</style>
```

### Overriding CSS styles

If the above seems too much an overhead to just apply one extra style to a component, you may override any styling with one of your own.

Simply choose a selector that will come out on top. Usually by using a stronger selector or using the same selector but being in a later CSS file (order does matter if the selector is the same).

For a more in-depth discussion of this, see: [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

In short: CSS was made so a style definition can be overriden by a later style definition or a more specific selector. There is no need to "unload" the current style to apply your own styling. Simply override it.

This also helps browser caching, since you always have the same CSS files sent to the browser, which it can keep in the cache.

Example for overriding:

```css
/* Strongly override using an ID and element name */
#app em {
  font-style: italic;
}

/* Only override em (might not work if there are more specific selectors) */
em {
  font-style: italic;
}

/* Only use em but give it a specific class */
em.italic {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

In general, check your browser developer tools which selectors applied to the element, then choose an appropriate selector to override the style.